# Python SSL Socket Error ssl.SSLCertVerificationError

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl

I was testing examples from Python SSL documentation,
and then I try use my own certificate it pop out this:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
```

I known this error is happening, because I am using self-signed certificate,
but I will not spent a lot of money, because it need to be varyfied.
I want to skip veryfication so it will use certificate as encryption.
How can I do that using that code:

Client:

```
import socket
import ssl
hostname = 'localhost'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
```

Server:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.load_cert_chain('certs/setver.crt', 'certs/private.key')
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as sock:
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8443))
    sock.listen(5)
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True) as ssock:
        conn, addr = ssock.accept()
        # Rest of the code...
```

Comment: It seems like this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61307557/self-signed-certificate-with-python-ssl-socket)

Comment: Oh, yes that works, thanks. But what do I do now with this question? Like delete or freeze? @Sebastian